# How can I fix no HDMI sound output, despite HDMI sound option being available in sound settings?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, sound, hdmi

So I'm new here, but after trying my best to sort it out myself, I have to ask what I'm missing.

I have Ubuntu 12.04, on a Thinkpad SL400 with nVidia GeForce 9300m GS. I've upgraded the nVidia driver to the "recommended" version in the Additional Drivers section.

Video output to my Toshiba HD TV via HDMI works fine, but not audio. The audio system settings show 4 options:

- HDMI/DisplayPort
- Digital Output (S/PDIF)
- Headphones
- Speakers

The speakers on the laptop produce sound, but the HDMI speakers do not.

I appreciate any help on solving this.

Answer (score -1):

Roll back the Nvidia driver, problem solved. THere is a bug in the new driver, but version 7.15.11.7597 works.